# Mi bucle do-while solo se repite una vez

Tags: java, while

Este es el bucle do-while que se repite solo una vez:

```java
do {
    System.out.println("Introduce un número válido del 1 al 10");
    NUM1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
} while (NUM1<=1 && NUM1 >= 10);
```

Comment: Las tabulaciones estan bien, no se porque sale asi al ponerlo en la publicación

Comment: Pon el código entre tres tildes graves (```) para lograr que tu código se vea correctamente.

Comment: solo se ejecuta una vez puesto que no es posible que un número sea <= 1 y al mismo tiempo >= 10. Para poder implementar el funcionamiento que deseas deberías cambiar el operador && por || que indica que se cumpla una de las dos condiciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que nada, es importante definir bien las variables siguiendo una correcta nomenclatura: por ejemplo, el uso de mayúsculas en toda la variable como en tu caso `NUM1` no es el correcto puesto que solo en variables que son finales, es decir constantes y no va a cambiar se debe usar esa nomenclatura.

```java
int NUM1 = 2; // NO
int num1 = 2; // SI
```

Lo segundo, si quieres que tu condición se cumpla es importante que entiendas bien que hacen los operadores `&&` y `||`.

Te dejo un ejemplo muy sencillo:

```java
int num = 5; // Esta es tu variable

// Con || basta con que se cumpla una condición.
if (num <= 5 || num >= 10) {
    // Cuando el num es menor o igual a 5 o bien cuando el número es mayor o igual a 10 (Si se cumple uno ya es suficiente)
    // Por lo tanto si el num es 6, 7, 8 o 9 no se cumple la condición.
}
        
// Con && se tiene que cumplir ambas condiciones
if (num <= 5 && num >= 1) {
    // Cuando el num es menor o igual que 5 y también es mayor o igual que 1 (Se tiene que cumplir ambos)
    // Por lo tanto si num no es 1, 2, 3, 4 o 5 no se cumple la condición.
}
```

Para que tu bucle funcione tendría que quedar de la siguiente manera:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner para leer
        int num1; // Variable de entero para guardar lo leído.

        do {
            System.out.print("Introduce un número válido del 1 al 10: ");

            // Convirtiendo el tipo String a int con parseInt
            num1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

            // Usando el método que te da la clase Scanner para leer enteros
            // num1 = sc.nextInt();
        } while (num1 < 1 || num1 > 10); // Fíjate que he quitado los = porque si no el 1 y el 10 no sería válido.
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, ahora me queda más claro, para la próxima vez seguro que lo tendré más en cuenta